Can I Wire a Thermocouple Like a PT100 Sensor
I have an IoT multi-channel controller which can accept PT100 sensors (2-wire or 3-wire). I don't have any PT100 sensors, however I do have K-type thermocouple wire. Is there any way to wire in the thermocouple to mimic a PT100 sensor? I don't need huge accuracy; ±2°C would be fine.

I would would recommend to buy some PT100 sensors, a converter from thermocouple to PT100 would be much more expensive than that.

Basically, no.
Pt100 sensors are resistive. A small current is driven through them and the voltage across them monitored. Resistance will vary from 100 Ω (hence the name) at 0°C to about 138 Ω at 100°C.
Theremocouples rely on the Seebeck effect where a voltage is generated by temperature difference between two dissimilar metals' junctions - one the sensor and the other the reference. These signals are typically low millivolt in level.
It is possible to design an input accept either but it sounds like your's doesn't.
